# Eror: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript, notifications

I stuck with error = Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. Actually, I want to make Notification list and I don't know what mistake  I made.

I stuck with error = Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. Actually, I want to make Notification list and I don't know what mistake  I made.

HTML

```
<ng-container *ngIf="notificationModal">
      <div class="side-panel__notif-container">
        <div class="side-panel__notify-header">
        <span class="side-panel__usr-profile-close" (click)="clkNotifcationPnl()">
          <fa-icon [icon]="faClose"></fa-icon>
        </span>
        <span class="side-panel__usr-noti-hdr">Notifications</span><br>
      </div>
      <div class="side-panel__notify-body">
        <div class="side-panel__user-notif-cont">
          <div class="drop-content">
         <ul class="mt-2 list-group notify-contents">
          <li *ngFor="let items of notify">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
              <div class="notify-img">
                <span [ngStyle]="{'background-image': loadProfilePic()}" class="side-panel__user-notif-img fa"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 pd-l0">{{items.notifyFromName}}
             <p>{{items.notifyMessage}}</p> 
            <p class="time">{{items.notifyDate}}</p>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ul>
        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
```

**Component**

```
public onClickUserNotif() {
   this.headerService.isLoading = true;
    return this.commonService.getNotificationList().subscribe((res) => {
      if (res['status'].code === 0) {
        this.headerService.isLoading = false;
        let notify = res['notification']
        if(notify.length > 0) {
          this.notificationModal = true;

          console.log(notify);


        }

      }
    });

  }
```

And this value come out when I `console.log(notify)`

[image]

Comment: scope of the `notify` is not the class, but a function. `this.notify = res['notification']` would make sense

Comment: I've follow your code but when I click to open notification I still got this error `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays`

Comment: @Pravu does it give you a `line number` for the error? Where is the error occurring?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer The error occuring from this ` <li *ngFor="let items of notify">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let notify = res['notification']
```

#### That creates block level scope, the local scope will never reflect this value. Angular binds to local scope, not block level. So you need to bind a local variable outside of that function.

```js
class ComponentName {
    notify: any[];
    // ...
   onClickUserNotif() {
       // ...
       this.notify = res['notification'];
   }
}
```

Edit:

## We know the following.

- prior to my suggestion you didn't have a locally scoped `notify`
- angular wont throw an error on a null value
- creating the locally scoped `notify` didn't solve the issue.

## Then only solutions/issues that I can see is either:

- You're looking at `HTML` that doesn't correspond to the `.ts` file you're working with, or
- `res['notification']` is being mutated in your `commonService` and `notify` is receiving that change.

#### Sidenote:

- In your `ngOnInit` you're subscribing to the *same* service that you subscribe to in your other function. I don't see why you're resubscribing.
- You use `takeWhile()` to try and mitigate active subscriptions, however you're only influencing the outer subscription. Not the inner subscription.

Comment: I've follow your code but when I click to open notification I still got this error `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays`

Comment: Can you add your full .ts file? I have a sneaky suspicion that you're binding `this.notify` somewhere else

Comment: @Pravu Which of the issues I outlined was the cause?

Comment: I think it problem come from `commonService`

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to play on a safe side, make sure you have this array at all times:

```
class ComponentName {
    notify: any[] = []; // assign an empty array
    // ...
   onClickUserNotif() {
       // ...
       this.notify = res['notification'];
   }
}

// In the template, use the ? to indicate that the might be no properties yet: 
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 pd-l0">{{items?.notifyFromName}}
             <p>{{items?.notifyMessage}}</p> 
            <p class="time">{{items?.notifyDate}}</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: As per the error he gave `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'`, `notify` is clearly defined, but as an object, not as an array.